# How to Multiply a Wave Function by a Pauli Matrix?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, notation, observables

Let's say I have a random wave function of $|\psi\rangle=(2+i)|0\rangle+(4-i)|1\rangle$ and I want to find the average value of the Pauli matrix with this function. How would I go about that? I tried $\langle\psi|\sigma_x|\psi\rangle$ then going to $\langle\psi|\sigma_x\psi\rangle$, but don't I end up getting rid of my $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ in my $|\psi\rangle$? That would make it so I couldn't multiply $|\psi\rangle$ by $\langle\psi|$, right?

Comment: Did you leave out some parentheses in your wavefunction? $2+i|0\rangle$ is not the same as $(2+i)|0\rangle$. The former does not actually make sense.

Comment: What did you calculate for $ \sigma_x|\psi\rangle$? Do you understand what $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are as column vectors?

Comment: @Ghoster I did leave out parentheses, sorry. For $\sigma_x|\psi\rangle$ I got $(2+1)+(4-i)$ which is $6$. I got that from converting the Pauli matrix into dirac notation giving me $|0\rangle \langle1|+|1\rangle \langle0|$ which I got from here, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/14062/

Comment: Actually, I think I may have figured it out. When multiplying the $|0\rangle \langle1|$ to the $|1\rangle$ from $psi$, I have that $|0\rangle$ left over after my $\langle1|1\rangle$ goes to 1, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.